# jquery not loading. I need help in adding jquery to my project. It is not loading the javascript files

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have three jquery files under WebContent>js folder. I tried including these files into my jsp pages using the following, but there is no javascript file loaded. My jsp page is inside WEB-INF>view>welcome.jsp . I have checked using firebug and tried searching over the internet for solution but nothing seems to be working.

```html
<script src="<c:url value='/js/jquery-1.11.2.js'/>"></script>
<script src="<c:url value='/js/jquery-ui.js'/>"></script>
<script src="<c:url value='/js/datePicker.js'/>"></script>
```

Comment: try <script src="/js/jquery-1.11.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  try to drag your file from solution it will give you the correct path

Comment: i don't believe you are searching for a solution

Comment: Why don't you try and see the path of the JS file which is getting generated in the browser? Maybe the issue is in your path.

Answer (score 0):

Either try our big friend google and some common sense, or use the foolproof cdn:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

(datepicker is included in jquery ui, no need to load it seperately)

Comment: Regarding Common Sense: I cannot use the CDN as I won't be connected to internet while demonstrating it. datePicker is my custom javascript file not anything which comes with jquery.

Comment: @SubhasishBhattacharjee then use the correct path , just drag the file to your code  it will give you the correct path

Comment: just to clarify myself: I have placed the files inside WebContent>js? so the path which is showing in console of firebug  "http://localhost:8080/DatePicker/js/jquery-ui.js" should find the files.. is it? DatePicker is my project name.

Comment: Well, depends on the server configuration... Try to access the js files directly in the browser. Can you open them?